# Apache сервер грузиться вечно

Tags: apache, веб-сервер

В конфиге httpd.conf сделал так, чтоб apache сервер работал через айпи и порт 192.160.136.188:80(мой публичный айпи адрес) и при этом настроил порт форвардинг на этот же айпи и порт, но сайт грузиться только на устройствах, которые подключены к вайфаю на котором хоститься сервер, а на устройствах которые подключены к другим сетям, сайт застреет на загрузке(я в апаче новенький, не бейте)

---

---------комплектация пк---------

OC:Windows 10

CPU: Intel Core i5

Роутер: Redmi 1BDE 5G

---

Больше я ничего не менял, виртуальных хостов нет, использую XAMPP

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Если локально все работает, а из вне нет, то проблема не в ПК и не в аппаче. Ваш публичный адрес кажется каким то не публичным и не пингуется.

Comment: @SwaD спасибо, приду домой попробую, скажу если не заработало

Comment: @SwaD я пинганул выше сказанный мной айпи с телефона (на мобильном интернете) потери пакетов нет, но когда на мобильном интернете захожу на сайт(по айпи), то идёт вечная загрузка.

Comment: ¯\\(ツ)/¯ Ковыряйте сеть. Возможно ошиблись в настройках роутера. Отдельно посмотрите логи вашего апача, до него запрос то вообще доходит.

Comment: @SwaD понял в чем проблема, оказывается нужно ssh подключение к "белому айпи" где нужен ключ, инными словами придеться покупать онлайн VPS сервак, простыми словами я все это время пытался организовать домашний сервер. Короче я закрываю вопрос